# Use a button on a UICollectionViewCell to display data from an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, uicollectionview

I have an array of `NSStrings`, one `UILabel` & a `UICollectionView`.

**My Question:**

I want the array's count to determine how many `UICollectionViewCell`'s there are.

Each `UICollectionViewCell` contains a button. Upon click, I want this button to cause the data in the array that corresponds to the `UICollectionViewCell`'s number to be displayed in the label.

For example, if the user clicks on the 13th `UICollectionViewCell`'s button, then the 13th `NSString` in the array would become the `UILabel`'s text.

**What I have done:**

I have made my own subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` for the nib file that I use for all of the `UICollectionViewCell`s, & connected the button to the .h file as a `IBAction`. I have also imported the `MainViewController.h`, which is the one that contains the array property that stores the `NSString`s.

When I edit the code in the `UICollectionViewCell`'s action, I cannot access the array property. The button does work - I placed an NSLog in the `IBAction`'s method, which does work.

I have searched through tens of other answers on SO, but none answer my specific question. I can update this with samples of my code if requested.

Comment: Any follow up on this issue?

Comment: My main problem was that I was that the cell I was using was not an instance of my custom UICollectionViewCell subclass. I was using a regular UICollectionViewCell instance. Rookie mistake. Thanks for all of help!

Comment: @tagabek Maybe Anupdas should be accepted?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I have made my own subclass of UICollectionViewCell for the nib file
>   that I use for all of the UICollectionViewCells, and connected the
>   button to the .h file as a IBAction.

If you connect the IBAction to the subclass of collectionViewCell you would need to create a delegate to make the touch event available in the viewController where you are displaying the data.

One easy tweak is to add the button the collectionViewCell, connect it's IBOutlet to the cell. But not IBAction. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`  add an eventHandler for button in that viewController containing collectionView.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Dequeue your cell

    [cell.button addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(collectionViewCellButtonPressed:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;

}


- (IBAction)collectionViewCellButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button{

    //Acccess the cell
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = button.superView.superView;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSString *title = self.strings[indexPath.row];

    self.someLabel.text = title;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this..

**In YourCollectionViewCell.h**

Create an IBOutlet not IBAction called button for the UIButton that you added to the xib. Remember you should connect the outlet to the cell object not to the file owner in the xib.

**MainViewController.m**

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
  [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return cell;
} 

-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
  NSLog(@"%d : %@",sender.tag,[array objectAtIndex:sender.tag]);
  self.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
 }
```

**Edit- Handle multiple sections**

```
 -(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
 {
  NSIndexPath  *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell: (UICollectionViewCell *)sender.superview.superview];

NSLog(@"Section : %d  Row: %d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);

if (0 == indexPath.section) {
    self.textLabel.text = [firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else if(1 == indexPath.section)
{
     self.textLabel.text = [secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

}
```

Comment: How will you handle when section also should be used?

Comment: Not possible to handle multiple sections.. But here OP stores the details in an array and taking the appropriate data correspond to the cell number. Which intern means he is having only one section. If he has multiple section he cannot use array. I saw your answer its more generic. But i think my code is enough

Comment: I actually have 4 sections. Can you explain why I cannot use an array?

Comment: Then how will you identify data from array? You have only cell number ie indexPath.row.. For each sections its count is like Sec1: 0,1,2.. Sec:0,1,2.. . So how can you identify the data in the array belongs to which section using the array index?? You cannot use a single array. Need different arrays for different sections. So it is better to use a dictionary in your case

Comment: @tagabek You can use array very well. You need format like this way. You should have an array of dictionaries. Consider each of these dictionaries as your sections. Each section dictionary would have an array or rows. So that it is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

> When I edit the code in the UICollectionViewCell's action, I cannot access the array property.

That's because you connected the button action to the "wrong" object. It needs to be connected to the MainViewController (or whoever it is that *does* have access to the array property).

You are going to have several tasks to perform:

- Receive the button action message.
- Access the array (the *model* for the data).
- Throw a switch saying which cell should now have its label showing.
- Tell the collection view to `reloadData`, thus refreshing the cells.

All those tasks should most conveniently belong to *one* object. I am presuming that this is MainViewController (and thus I am presuming that MainViewController is the delegate/datasource of the collection view).

Comment: The button action cannot connect to the MainViewController because it is inside of the UICollectionViewCell. The label is actually a part of the MainViewController.xib and not the UICollectionViewCell.nib (Sorry, I should have specified). Let's say I have 50 UICollectionViewCells in the UICollectionView. There are 50 buttons within the entire collection view - one in each cell. I want to connect each index of the array to each cell. I hope that helps specify. I appreciate the help!

Comment: "The button action cannot connect to the MainViewController". Certainly it can. Perhaps you can't set it by drawing out the connection in the storyboard, but you can set it in code (in your implementation of `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` would be a very convenient place, and indeed there's now another answer showing you how to do that - at this rate you won't have to do *any* thinking for yourself).